# Am I using typedef structures and arrays correctly to read my file? It is not opening

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm a beginner in data structures with C, I have taken C programming but I've only touched a little bit on structures in the course and I have not kept up with it.

Anyways, I'm trying to make a program that will read data into an array of  structures from a file and print out the contents of the array you have populated. I need help figuring this out.. I'm honestly not too sure if I'm doing this correctly either... :/

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance! :)

This is what I tried so far

Here's my code:

FYI - The file I'm trying to open is DataFile.txt

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define ARRAY_SIZE 30


//Struct contains 3 fields, name, age, salary
typedef struct
{
    char name[SIZE];
    int age;
    int salary;
} data;

data a[ARRAY_SIZE];
FILE * fp = fopen("DataFile.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error %s.\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}


int GetData()
{
    int i = 0;

    fscanf(fp, "%s", a[i].name);
    while(fp && i<ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i].age);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i].salary);
    i++;
}

return i;
}

void ShowData( int records_read)
{
    //Print text file data on screen
    for(int i=0;i<records_read;i++)
    {
    printf("%s %d %d\n", a[i].name, a[i].age, a[i].salary);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char name[256];
    int i = 0;
    int records_read;


    //Call the method, getData
    i = GetData();

    //Prompt and read input from the user
    printf("Pick a number from 1 to 10:");
    scanf("%d", &records_read);

    //Call the method, showData
    ShowData(records_read);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The program works if I don't put this part of the code in:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("DataFile.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error %s.\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

BUT the output is just a list of zeros..

Comment: You can't have function calls or `if` statements outside of functions

Comment: The code that tries to open the file should be in `main()`, not at top-level. You should also learn how to use function parameters instead of global variables.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While in this case the error is rather obvious, you should always copy&paste the complete and exact error message if you get an error during compilation. You can't try to open the file because you cannot even run your program due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick answer: At first, try to split `FILE * fp = fopen("DataFile.txt", "r");` into two parts as one is the variable declaration `FILE * fp = NULL;` and the other one is the assignment expression `fp = fopen("DataFile.txt", "r");`. And then keeps the part of the variable declaration out of all the functions, while moves both the part of the assignment and the if-statement `if (fp == NULL){...}` into function `GetData()`. The code might work in this case.